# How to test disabled field in ruby on rails and assert_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-selectors, integration-testing

I want to test presence of disabled field generated in rails(5) view helper

```
form_for(@metric) do |f|
  f.text_field :type, disabled: true
end
```

it creates HTML

```
<input id="metric_type" type="text" name="metric[type]" value="Gamfora::Metric::Point" disabled="disabled">
```

It should be probably just

```
<input id="metric_type" type="text" name="metric[type]" value="Gamfora::Metric::Point" disabled>
```

but it is OK and do the job.

---

In Firebug I verify that CSS selector is `input#metric_type:disabled`.

But when I use it in controller(+view) tests

```
assert_select "input#metric_type:disabled"
```

I get error

```
RuntimeError: xmlXPathCompOpEval: function disabled not found
```

Is there any way, how to test that input selected by ID is disabled?

Answer (score 7):

One solution is

```
assert_select ".field input#metric_type" do |input|
    assert input.attr("disabled").present?
end
```